# Keycodes / onclick enter, show Multiple innerHTML names

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

When I move the 4 arrows on the keyboard, the green hover color moves over each button. I want when I press "Enter" to write the number that corresponds to each box. For example now I have "columns" and it writes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. I want to write One Two Three etc .. Of course I use Handebars, Backcone, Lodash so I do not want to change anything in HTML (Handlebars.compile) Thank you very much ..

```js
var columns = 0;
var rowButtons = 0;

var $rows = $('.multiple');
var liSelected;

var arrows = {
    left: 37, 
    up: 38, 
    right: 39, 
    down: 40, 
    enter: 13
    };
  
  
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (Object.values(arrows).indexOf(e.which) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.multiple li').removeClass('selected');

switch (e.which) {
  case arrows.up:
    rowButtons = rowButtons == 0 ? $rows.length - 1 : rowButtons - 1;
    break;

  case arrows.down:
    rowButtons = rowButtons == $rows.length - 1 ? 0 : rowButtons + 1;
    break;

  case arrows.left:
    $buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
    columns = columns == 0 ? $buttonsInRow.length - 1 : columns - 1;
    break;

  case arrows.right:
    $buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
    columns = columns == $buttonsInRow.length - 1 ? 0 : columns + 1;
    break;

case arrows.enter:
// find the column and row position:
$buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
var position = (rowButtons * 6 ) + columns + 1; 
 rowButtons = rowButtons == $rows.click;
 
 document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = columns;

break;
     }

    buttonSelected = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li:eq(' + columns + ')');
    buttonSelected.addClass('selected');
}
});

// Click function on handlebars 
// Affect href ie. <a href="#" patterns="one"> (It doesn't work on enter(13)
var ListView = BacListViewkbone.View.extend({
events: {
'click a': 'onClick'
},
render: function() {
var rawHTML = _template({ items: myList });
this.$el.html(rawHTML);
this.$items = this.$el.find('a');
return this;
},

onClick: function(e) {
var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('patterns');
dispatcher.trigger(dispatcher.EventKeys.PATTERNS_SELECTED, myList[id]);
}
});
function init(options) {
dispatcher.register(evs);
new ListView(options).render();
}
  
return {
init: init
}
```

```css
li.selected {
  background: green;
}

.multiple, .allRows li{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.allRows a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #555; 
  color: #222; 
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;

} 

#screen {
  background:#222;
  color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding:30px 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="allRows">
<div class="multiple">
<li><a href="#" patterns="one" id="one" onClick="one()">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="two" id="two" onClick="two()">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="three" id="three" onClick="three()">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="four" id="four" onClick="four()">Four</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="five" id="five" onClick="five()">Five</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="six" id="six" onClick="six()">Six</a></li>
</div>
<div class="multiple">
<li><a href="#" patterns="seven" id="seven" onClick="seven()">Seven</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="eight" id="eight" onClick="eight()">Eight</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="nine" id="nine" onClick="nine()">Nine</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="ten" id="ten" onClick="ten()">Ten</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="eleven" id="eleven" onClick="eleven()">Eleven</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="twelve" id="twelve" onClick="twelve()">Twelve</a></li></div>
</ul>


<div id="screen">Numbers</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the translation on the elements html themselves, you'll need to have an object mapping the values to the names to be output.
Here's a minimalist example:

```js
const numberNameMap = {
  1: 'one',
  2: 'two',
  3: 'three',
  4: 'four',
  5: 'five'
};

const select = document.querySelector('select');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

select.addEventListener('change', ({ target: { value } }) => {
  output.textContent = numberNameMap[value];
});
```

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```js
var columns = 0;
var rowButtons = 0;

var $rows = $('.multiple');
var liSelected;

var arrows = {
    left: 37, 
    up: 38, 
    right: 39, 
    down: 40, 
    enter: 13
    };
   
  
  
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (Object.values(arrows).indexOf(e.which) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.multiple li').removeClass('selected');

switch (e.which) {
  case arrows.up:
    rowButtons = rowButtons == 0 ? $rows.length - 1 : rowButtons - 1;
    break;

  case arrows.down:
    rowButtons = rowButtons == $rows.length - 1 ? 0 : rowButtons + 1;
    break;

  case arrows.left:
    $buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
    columns = columns == 0 ? $buttonsInRow.length - 1 : columns - 1;
    break;

  case arrows.right:
    $buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
    columns = columns == $buttonsInRow.length - 1 ? 0 : columns + 1;
    break;
     }

    buttonSelected = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li:eq(' + columns + ')');
    buttonSelected.addClass('selected');
    


  }
});


$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    //get id of the selected li>a element
    var elementId = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0].children[0].id;
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = elementId;
  }
})
```

```css
li.selected {
  background: green;
}

.multiple, .allRows li{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.allRows a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #555; 
  color: #222; 
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;

} 

#screen {
  background:#222;
  color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding:30px 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="allRows">
<div class="multiple">
<li><a href="#" patterns="one" id="one">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="two" id="two">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="three" id="three">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="four" id="four">Four</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="five" id="five">Five</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="six" id="six">Six</a></li>
</div>
<div class="multiple">
<li><a href="#" patterns="seven" id="seven">Seven</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="eight" id="eight">Eight</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="nine" id="nine">Nine</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="ten" id="ten">Ten</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="eleven" id="eleven">Eleven</a></li>
<li><a href="#" patterns="twelve" id="twelve">Twelve</a></li></div>
</ul>


<div id="screen">Numbers</div>
```

I've removed

```
case arrows.enter:
// find the column and row position:
$buttonsInRow = $('.multiple:eq(' + rowButtons + ') li');
var position = (rowButtons * 6 ) + columns + 1; 
rowButtons = rowButtons == $rows.click;

document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = columns;
break;
```

and added

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        //get id of the selected li>a element
        var elementId = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0].children[0].id;
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = elementId;
    }
})
```

After your `window.keypress` function for a dedicated `Enter` button event listener, also removed all the onClick functions under the assumptions that you thought of using them to get these values but ended up seeing how much work that logic will be so instead I look at the `li` element with the `selected` class and use it's child `a tag`'s ID since it is already a name value of the numeric value instead of having to create an array of values for a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code to do exactly what you want. Try this

```js
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if( [37, 38, 39, 40, 13].includes(e.which) ){
        e.preventDefault();

        let $col     = $('.multiple li.selected');
        let $row     = $col.closest('.multiple');
        let $nextCol = $col;
        let $nextRow = $row;
        
        if( [37, 38, 39, 40].includes(e.which) && $col.length === 0 ){
            $('.multiple:first-child').find('li:first').addClass('selected');
            return;
        }

        switch (e.which) {
            case 38: // up key
                $nextRow = $row.is(':first-child') ? $row.siblings(":last-child") : $row.prev();
                break;

            case 40: // down key
                $nextRow = $row.is(':last-child') ? $row.siblings(":first-child") : $row.next();
                break;

            case 37: // left key
                $nextCol = $col.is(':first-child') ? $col.siblings(":last-child") : $col.prev();
                break;

            case 39: // right key
                $nextCol = $col.is(':last-child') ? $col.siblings(":first-child") : $col.next();
                break;
            case 13: // enter key
                if($col.length > 0) $('#screen').text($col.find('a').trigger('click').text());
                break;
        }

        $('.multiple li').removeClass('selected');
        $nextRow.find('li').eq($nextCol.index()).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```css
li.selected {
  background: green;
}

.multiple, .allRows li{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.allRows a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #555; 
  color: #222; 
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;

} 

#screen {
  background:#222;
  color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding:30px 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="allRows">
    <div class="multiple">
        <li><a href="#" patterns="one" id="one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="two" id="two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="three" id="three">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="four" id="four">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="five" id="five">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="six" id="six">Six</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="multiple">
        <li><a href="#" patterns="seven" id="seven">Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="eight" id="eight">Eight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="nine" id="nine">Nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="ten" id="ten">Ten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="eleven" id="eleven">Eleven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" patterns="twelve" id="twelve">Twelve</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>

<div id="screen">Numbers</div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it works 100%. Thank you very much for simplifying the code. By the way, do you know why when I press "enter (13)", href <a href="#" patterns="one"> does not work, I mean how can this be affected by the click as you did with innerHTML text?

Comment: @ric12g you mean when you press enter, in doesn't display the text or you have some other code that is supposed to fire?

Comment: I have updated my code ,just to take a look at href attribute. Yes when I press enter href doesn't work with text. If you can just take a look.. thanks a lot

Comment: It works with your own code, but only for the text ... not for the text and the href together. The href is the link that performs a function. Normally together with the text, this should also click the href but it does not understand enter(13) .. can you understand why from the js code? Thanks...

Comment: No, that's the strange thing..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241996/discussion-between-ric12g-and-ruleboy21).

Comment: Still the same.. I think I have to call the href function nside enter key. But i don't know how to do it..

Comment: @ric12g I've updated my answer with the 'fix'. Kindly check it out.